# Apache Zeppelin - How to use Helium framework in Apache Zeppelin

Tags: apache, apache-zeppelin

From Zeppelin-0.7, Zeppelin started supporting Helium plugins/packages using Helium Framework. However, I am not able to view any of the plugin on Helium page (localhost:8080/#/helium). As per this [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2004), I placed sample Helium.json (available on [s3](https://s3.amazonaws.com/helium-package/helium.json)) under /local-repo/helium-registry-cache. However, after that I got NPE while restarting Apache Zeppelin service.

I have tried Zeppelin 0.7 as well as Zeppelin 0.8.0 snaptshot versions. In particular, I want to use map Helium package - [Helium-Map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/volume-leaflet) in Zeppelin note.

Can some one point me to any guide or documentation having detailed steps of using Helium package in Zeppelin? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Zeppelin 0.7.x

Zeppelin 0.7.x doesn't support the online registry. In other words, 
 Zeppelin doesn't use `helium.json`. So you need to install each package by yourself.

1. clone the helium package what you want to install
2. modify the `artifact` value to the **absolute path** considering your local machine in `helium-xxx.json`
3. copy `zeppelin-xxx.json` into the `$ZEPPELIN_HOME/helium` directory (create if it doesn't exist yet)
4. restart Zeppelin and go to the `localhost:8080/#/helium` page, then install the package.

#### Zeppelin 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT

Zeppelin 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT supports the online registry. So you can install without any preparation.

But the NPE problem you've faced was fixed after https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/2380.

So please `git pull origin master` and rebuild it :)

- FYI, Now Zeppelin provides proxy functionality for helium. Refer https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/2363

Comment: Can someone explain steps 2 and 3 please? What is artifact value? Where should helium-xxx.json and zeppelin-xxx.json be?

Comment: Also other than the package.json and some unimportant files, there is just an index.js file in the zip, is this all I need? And why do I get a blank page when I try to access helium?

Comment: Hi, Let's say you want to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/zeppelin-plotly-bubble. In this case, (step3) copy `zeppelin-plotly-bubble.json` into your `$ZEPPELIN_HOME/helium` (create if `helium dir doesn't exist) and (step2) modify the `$ZEPPELIN_HOME/helium/zeppelin-plotly-bubble.json`'s **artifact** value to proper path in your local machine.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Get an error though in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742740/why-does-helium-give-unexpected-token-error-in-apache-zeppelin) question.