# How do I add maps to Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am trying to follow [this](http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/tutorial-with-map-visualization-in.html) tutorial, which more or less works for me, but in the final screenshots, he has selected a map icon in Zeppelin, which I do not have. I cannot find any help on installing map support to Zeppelin. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please? TIA!

I use Zep 0.7.0 and HDP-2.6.0.3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Zeppelin - How to use Helium framework in Apache Zeppelin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342619/apache-zeppelin-how-to-use-helium-framework-in-apache-zeppelin)

Comment: Hi, I think the map feature is part of Helium, so you need to either configure your 0.7.0 for Helium support and this map feature, or go for 0.8.0 snapshot. This is answered better here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342619/apache-zeppelin-how-to-use-helium-framework-in-apache-zeppelin

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

You have to download zeppelin-leaflet from helium(In the upper right corner click on the login indicator and select Helium), this gives the globe symbol in the application