# Why does helium give 'Unexpected token' error in Apache Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am trying to add [volume-leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/volume-leaflet) via helium to Apache zeppelin (0.7) as per [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342619/apache-zeppelin-how-to-use-helium-framework-in-apache-zeppelin/44350750#44350750) instructions. I get this error when trying to enable it:

```
./~/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css
Module parse failed: /usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/zeppelin/local-repo/vis/node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css Unexpected token (3:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (3:0)
at Parser.pp$4.raise (/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/zeppelin/local-repo/vis/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
at Parser.pp.unexpected (/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/zeppelin/local-repo/vis/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/zeppelin/local-    ... [some removed]... core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
at Storage.finished (/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/zeppelin/local-repo/vis/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
at /usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/zeppelin/local-repo/vis/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)
@ ./~/volume-leaflet/index.js 23:0-35
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi, if you go to README of volume-leaflet, It says It requires Zeppelin 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT+ but you used 0.7

Comment: you might create you own helium for 0.7 and map visualization.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how I would do that?

Comment: Here is a guide how to create new helium for 0.7.X http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/development/writingzeppelinvisualization.html But If you don't have trouble to use 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT, I recommend using it. It provides online registry so you don't need to donwload packages manually.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll try 0.8. Thanks again if you want to add an answer I'll accept it.